# Error ouput have symbol special in text

Tags: php

I have a sample code :

```
$text = '<a title="L'Oreal Pure Zone - 80ml">L'Oreal Pure Zone</a>';
```

When I echo code is error by symbol `'`

```
echo json_encode($text);
```

How to fix it ?

Comment: This is a good sign you should relearn the basics or at least strings.

Answer (score 0):

You have to [escape the single quotes](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.single):

```
$text = '<a title="L\'Oreal Pure Zone - 80ml">L\'Oreal Pure Zone</a>';
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$text = '<a title="L\'Oreal Pure Zone - 80ml">L\'Oreal Pure Zone</a>';
```

This is a possible way of doing that